# Given a third point $S$, show an equation of the line passing through $S$ and parallel to the line $PQ.$

Tags: geometry

Question: A person considers lines on the plane $\mathbb{R^2}$ to be in the form of:
$$X=t\cdot P+s\cdot Q$$
where $P$, $Q$ are two fixed different points and $s,$ $t$ are varying reals satisfying $s+t=1$. Given a third point $S$, show an equation of the line passing through $S$ and parallel to the line $PQ.$  Justify your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need another point on the line through $S,$ and the vector $Q-P$ is parallel to the given line through $P,Q.$ So another point on the line through $S$ parallel is $S+Q-P.$ Then in the desired form that line is $xS+y(S+Q-P),$ where $x+y=1.$